# simjacker: which SIMs are vulnerable?

Tags: vulnerability, simcard

[simjacker.com](https://simjacker.com) looks like a pretty serious security issue with SIM cards.  There's not much technical detail on their website though.  And it'd be nice to be able to already know which SIMs are vulnerable.

Unfortunately the [S@T technical specification](https://www.simalliance.org/files/S@T/S@T_Specifications_2009/S@T%2001.23%20v4.0.0%20(Release%202009).pdf) doesn't look very helpful to me.

Is there a simple way to know whether a SIM is vulnerable?

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](https://www.adaptivemobile.com/blog/simjacker-next-generation-spying-over-mobile), it's not the SIMs that are the concern, its if the carrier installs the S@T toolkit on it.

To detect the vulnerability, one would have to know how to detect the toolkit. [As of this writing, there appears to be no methods offered to the public to detect the toolkit]